# How can I output all the string arrays in a split string?

Tags: c#, string

I've written this code that splits "@" and ":"

```
var Split = Texts.Split(new char[] { '@' });
var Split1 = Texts.Split(new char[] { ':' });
```

I want to output all the string arrays to a file. I've tried and I get only one string, not all.

```
formatted = Split[0] + ":" + Split1[1];
File.WriteAllText(outputfile, formatted);
```

Here is my code:

```
public void CreateUsernameList(string targetfile,string outputfile)
{
    string[] texts = File.ReadAllLines(targetfile);
    string formatted = null;
    foreach(string Texts in texts)
    {
        var Split = Texts.Split(new char[] { '@' });
        var Split1 = Texts.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        formatted = Split[0] + ":" + Split1[1];
        File.WriteAllText(outputfile, formatted);
    }
}
```

Comment: var Split = Texts.Split(new char[] { '@', ':' });
File.WriteAllText(outputfile, string.Join(" ",formatted));

Comment: Can you show us an example of the lines you are parsing and the exact output you want?  What you currently have should give you everything before the first "@" and then everything between the first and second ":" (or the end of the line if there isn't a second)

Comment: this doesn't fix the problem this only outputs one string what I mean is I need to output all string not only one

Comment: Oh I see the problem.  `File.WriteAllText` in a loop is going to continuously overwrite the file over and over again.  Try putting your results into a `List<string>` and using `File.WriteAllLines` after the loop.

Comment: Ex. George@live.com:george

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuously overwriting the file in that loop.  Instead collect the results in a `List<string>` and then write that to the file.

```
public void CreateUsernameList(string targetfile,string outputfile)
{
    string[] texts = File.ReadAllLines(targetfile);
    string formatted = null;
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    foreach(string Texts in texts)
    {
        var Split = Texts.Split(new char[] { '@' });
        var Split1 = Texts.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        formatted = Split[0] + ":" + Split1[1];
        output.Add(formatted);
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(outputfile, output)
}
```

An alternative that will not use as much memory would be

```
public void CreateUsernameList(string targetfile,string outputfile)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(
        outputfile,
        File.ReadLines(targetfile)
            .Select(line => 
             {
                 var Split = line.Split(new char[] { '@' });
                 var Split1 = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                 return Split[0] + ":" + Split1[1];
             }
        )
    ); 
}
```

Comment: I see .. Thanks gonna add this to my references in the  future.

Answer (score 0):

As I dont see any format of data I can only guess that the error might be here:

formatted = Split[0] + ":" + Split1[1];

you are taking only single elements from each array of strings. try looping through all the elements in arrays Split and Split1 to print their values

Answer (score 0):

It's better to read file in lazy manner:

```
File.ReadLines(targetfile).ForEach(line =>
{
    File.AppendAllText("path", string.Join(":", Regex.Split(line, "@|:")
                               .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)));
});

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    internal static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (enumerable == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"'{nameof(enumerable)}' argument is null");
        using var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) action(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not Lazy if you use `ToList`

Comment: Oops... I forgot about custom `ForEach` )

Comment: Also this still overwrites the file on each loop.

Comment: Now the down side is that if they run this code a second time it's just going to append more stuff to the file instead of replacing it.